# Xcode 13.4.1 error: Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.

Tags: ios, xcode, cmake, cmakelists-options, cmake-custom-command

We are building an application that would be cross-platform and hence using CMake as the build system: Getting the below error when code signing is allowed using XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED "Yes"

Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code :

xcodebuild[7441:1813649] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore

xcodebuild[7441:1813649] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore

** BUILD FAILED **

Comment: any solutions there ?